# Red5 - AS3 - Recording output sounds 'robotic' and distorted on some Android phones

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, red5

I am using Red5 with AS3 (Adobe AIR) for recording voice. I am following this tutorial for doing the same: http://sziebert.net/posts/server-side-stream-recording-updated/

When I deploy my builds on mobile it works fine on the iPhone and iPad. Even on Android it works fine on some phones like the Nexus, Samsung S2 and Sony Xperia. However, on some phones like the Motorola and some of the cheaper handsets, the recorded output sounds 'robotic' and is distorted.

My microphone settings on AS3 are:

```
m_microphoneReference = Microphone.getMicrophone();

m_microphoneReference.rate = 44;
m_microphoneReference.gain = 100;
//m_microphoneReference.setSilenceLevel(10);
m_microphoneReference.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
```

I fiddled around with the microphone bit rates in AS3 and sound was a bit better. But I am trying to find the reason for this distortion. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying that there is an improvement in the quality when you lower the rate, that seems to indicate the phones in question are not up to the task. Nexus models are normally top-of-the-line so its no surprise that the perform well. I would suggest allowing a user to select the rate if they experience issues as well as informing them of potential issues with the "listed" devices and os versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mondain. However, is there a method to track these "listed" devices so that I can inform the user accordingly.

Comment: Nothing built-in no. The way you'd do that is look at the parameters passed at connect (similar to http user agent) and bounce it against your own list.